# How to make an initrd.img in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, initrd

[Environment: Ubuntu 10.04]

I've just finished compiling Linux-2.6.20 and wanna make it work, so I think I should add something to my grub2, as I finished

```
make modules_install
make install
```

in /boot/,I got

```
vmlinuz-2.6.20
System.map-2.6.20
config-2.6.20
```

So I just tried

```
mkinitramfs -o initrd.img-2.6.20 2.6.20
```

Then the file initrd.img-2.6.20 was generated, but after I type

```
update-grub2
```

That image file is not found! Does anyone know how to deal with this?

By the way,I really wonder from which files is initrd.img-2.6.20 generated? Because it seemed that I didn't even specify any source to generate this file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am using 2.6.32.59 version and the following steps work for me-

```
#sudo update-initramfs -c -k 2.6.32.59
#sudo update-grub
```